# Making a ToolStripSeparator horizontal in a vertical toolbar in WinForms

Tags: winforms, toolstrip

have Googled and cannot find out how to make a ToolStripSeparator "draw" an horizontal line in a toolbar that is aligned vertical.

The separator is drawn vertically which makes it awful.

Eg.
 
* - item

*
*
| <- separator 
*
*

when it should be

*
*
- <- separator 
*
*

Comment: I'm giving this the "Works-On-My-Machine" seal of approval. :)  I'm looking at a ToolStripSeparator in a vertical toolstrip right now.  The separator is painted horizontally - both in design and at runtime.

Comment: i guess a screenshot would be in order.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering, but I supplied an answer on how to custom draw it anyway. ;)

Comment: http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/484/separatorerror.jpg

Comment: found the problem must be:
ToolStrip.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.VerticalStackWithOverflow
else you get the problem I had.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own ToolStripRenderer and override the OnRenderSeparator to draw the line yourself.

```
protected override void OnRenderSeparator(ToolStripSeparatorRenderEventArgs e)
{
    using (var pen = new Pen(borderColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 5, e.Item.Size.Height / 2, e.Item.Size.Width - 5, e.Item.Size.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

Then you set the `Renderer` property of your toolstrip to the renderer you just made.

```
toolStrip.Renderer = new MyToolStripRenderer();
```